# Can I fit linear mixed model here?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, linear

I have measured heart rate(HR) in different rooms of the house and I have used two different groups of participants. The rooms they go through are from 1 to 8 in that order. Now I am interested if there is a significant change in HR when comparing the rest of the rooms to the first room. Also, I´d like to check if the groups differ in terms of HR. I have modelled it like this lmer(HR ~ room + (1|id), data = my data). I am not expecting a linear line but up and down changing HR in each room. I get somewhat strange results. Is linear mixed model appropriate here? Or what could do a better job? Here is some visualization below. Group 1 and 2 boxplots in different rooms and lines by id by the group.
[image: boxplot][image: linegraph]

Comment: What is the difference between the two groups ? The model you wrote does not take account of group differences. From the visualisations the only difference between the two groups appears to be higher variance in group 1, both within id and between id, and there is no discernable differences or trends between the rooms.

Comment: @RobertLong The first group slept overnight and the second group went for a march overnight. ie. the second group did not sleep. For me too it looks like that there are no differences but my results from the model look like there is a significant change in comparison to the first room in the rest of the rooms and that second and third are 4 HR lower.

Comment: Please include the model output in the question.